# Quantifying Mortgage Refinance Incentive: Why define the Refi Incentive as the log of Mortgage Rate/Market Rate

Tags: fixed-income, modeling

I'm reading this [research article](https://core.ac.uk/reader/7162608), where they are using survival analysis to study mortgage prepayments. In this article they define the mortgage holder's incentive to refinance as: $Refi = log(Mr_t$ $/$ $Mk_t) $ where $Mr_t$ is the Mortgage rate and $Mk_t$ is the market rate. Why is this methodology chosen instead of just taking the difference between the Mortgage rate and the Market rate ie ($Refi = $$Mr_t - Mk_t$).

Comment: Over time interest rates have varied widely, so perhaps the authors felt that the i.r. difference was not as important as the ratio  (or log thereof). I.e. compare 10% to 9% versus compare 2% vs 1%. They are both a 1% difference but it is much more salient and significant (action inducing) to people in the latter case. (But it is debatable, like many issues in research, and academics love to debate these points and propose alternative measures ;) ).

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks a lot!